# How to draw line in react

Tags: html, css

I need do something like that responsive with material ui and grid but i don't know how

[image]

Comment: you can use `hr` or `div` to draw the line.

Comment: an `<hr>` will do the job just fine but that `reactjs` tag is wrong

Answer (score 2):

That is not React, that is HTML and or CSS.
In HTML you can use

```
<hr />
```

With CSS you can use borders.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution by Image - Using Grid**

I wrote in the code how to do it like you ask for.

By using grid, (there is a default grid columns).

And if you want to learn more about grid you can play some nice game:
https://cssgridgarden.com

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.block {
  height: 38px;
  width: 391px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 20px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

hr {
  margin: auto 20px;
  border: 1.5px solid rgb(150, 150, 150);
}

.text {
  margin: auto 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <hr />
  <div class="text">or</div>
  <hr />
</div>
```